# TypeScript Proper Unhandled promise rejection for aws-sdk

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk

I'm trying to return the name of an AWS Secrets Manager Secret.

I have a working example WHEN it finds a match for my param, but throws the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:Unhandled promise rejection`

Looking for help on how to handle the rejection (or suppress it) and print out the name (if it exists) or print `secret doesn't exist` if it doesn't.

```
// Set Params for Describe Secret
const params = {SecretId: `${dir.name}`};

const response = sm.describeSecret(params).promise()

console.log((await response).Name)
```

I haven't been able to find much related to TS only JS. I'm also fairly new to JS/TS

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do what I wanted

```
const response = await sm.describeSecret(params).promise()
 .then((data) => data.Name).catch(() => {})
```